# How do I visualize a remote, url accessible vtk file in XTK?

Tags: xtk

Does anyone have an example of rendering a remote file in XTK (https://github.com/xtk/X)? Is this currently possible?

I tried swapping in a URL for the file location, like so:

```
// load a .vtk file
var skull = new X.object();
skull.load('https://s3.amazonaws.com/surfaces/skull.vtk');
```

No luck though... Any ideas?

UPDATE:
AWS now supports CORS on S3! Just took a little patience: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this should work!

Maybe it is a cross-origin error - it could be a simple fix on the remote server (the one hosting the .vtk file) like described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Oops! forgot to respond, and finally revisiting this.

I think you are right about CORS being the issue, but it looks like I might be out of luck with AWS. 

There is an outstanding issue with Amazon S3 and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. Check out this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=345866&

Any ideas on a workaround?